# autofs mount all devices from specific type

Tags: linux, mount, automounting, autofs

I want to mount **ALL USB** devices with one autofs entry.

I can't mount the device by it's ID, Label or something like that.
I need to duplicate it and don't know every single usb device on every single machine.

> It should be mount all devices from type USB with one entry.

All i know is to mount it by Label *(same problem >> don't know every single device label).*

my autofs share entry, with label looks like but only works if the label is right:

```
USBDEV -fstype=ntfs,rw,hard,rsize=8192,wsize=8192 :/dev/disk/by-label/USBDEV
```

Is it possible to do that with autofs like i need to?

Comment: Related: https://www.axllent.org/docs/view/auto-mounting-usb-storage/

Comment: Sorry, i need to say that the device should not be mounted without any access. That was one reason why i want to use something like autofs.